# Lose response from the server in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code that make 3 requests to a server, the code works fine with the request but when I receive the response the code fails, take avoid the first response and give me the third.

```
phone.open("POST", '/', true);
phone.setRequestHeader("Content-type", elmnt.getAttribute('ctype'));
phone.send(reqStr);
```

This is the code that catch the response.

```
phone = new ConstructorXMLHttpRequest();
onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(phone.readyState == 4){
        if(phone.status == 200){
        var val = phone.responseText;
        alert(phone.responseText)
        dataInsert(val);
        break;
        }else{
              alert("Problemas status:"+phone.status+" state:"+phone.readyState);
              break;
        }
            }

};
```

@Hemlock here is the code of the constructor:

```
function ConstructorXMLHttpRequest()
{
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest) /*XMLHttpRequest(Browsers Mozilla, Safari and Opera). */
      {
        return new XMLHttpRequest(); 
      }
      else if(window.ActiveXObject) /*IE*/
      {
      /*There a several difference between versions of IE, so
       * if the kids of MS release a new please put in this Array.*/
      var versionesObj = new Array(
      'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0',
      'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0',
      'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
      'Msxml2.XMLHTTP',
      'Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        for (var i = 0; i < versionesObj.length; i++)
        {
          try
          {
          return new ActiveXObject(versionesObj[i]);
          }
          catch (errorControlado)
          {
          }
        }
      }
throw new Error("Couldn't make a XMLHttpRequest");
}
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense and your `switch` block is useless.

Comment: Gonna copy that one and send it to DailyWTF.

Comment: Why is useless i used all the times this is the first time that give me this mistake.

Comment: a lot of the code is completely redundant. http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/Z9TJ5/ This code does the exact same and is neater.

Comment: Thanks @Raynos, i delete all the mistakes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason people think this is funny is because your `case` statement is A) useless because you don't actually want to take different actions depending on the state of the object, you actually only want to act on its status under one condition and B) your `case` is used in conjunction with an `if` statement, which is redundant - not to mention syntactically erroneous.

I think you're trying to do

```
    if(phone.readyState == 4){
        var val = phone.responseText;
        alert(val);
        dataInsert(val);
    }else{
        alert("Problemas status:"+phone.status+" state:"+phone.readyState);
    }
```

I also think you should look into using a 3rd party library like jQuery to do your ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getData.html',
    success: function(val) {
        alert(val);
        dataInsert(val);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but is cause me the same mistake, give me just  the last of the 3 responses, i make the request all inside a function so is like if the javascript is replacing the value of the responseText with the last.

Comment: There is definitely a language barrier on this problem. I know how to read broken English quite well and I'm not quite following what @hidura is saying the problem is. What do you mean it gives you the last of the the 3 responses? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Well the request to the server send a response i make 3 in the same function one after the other but the system just show the third.

Comment: To fix that problem, you'll have to post the code in `ConstructorXMLHttpRequest`, but it probably has to do with all the requests sharing the same onreadystatechange handler. Or maybe you're sending them all on the same instance of `phone`.

Comment: I posted the code, but probably use the same instance, i will check thanks @Hemlock

Comment: Thanks to your help i fixed using jQuery.ajax()!

Comment: Good. You'll be much happier in the long term. :)